# Using filter in a custom list in React Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I've been trying to implement a filter feature into react admin, for a regular list I haven't had any issue, done it for multiple lists. I used these [docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#building-a-custom-filter) and it was pretty straight forward.

The issue here is I'm using ListContextProvider and for the life of me, cannot find how to implement filters using this. Trying to implement using the docs provided above yields no results. Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {
  Datagrid,
  TextField,
  ReferenceField,
  FunctionField,
  Pagination,
  Loading,
  ListContextProvider,
  useQuery,
} from 'react-admin';
import keyBy from 'lodash/keyBy'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import "../../css/styles.css";

function CustomList(props) {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(50);
  const [sort, setSort] = useState({ field: 'id', order: 'DESC' })
  const { data, total, loading, error } = useQuery({
    type: 'getList',
    resource: 'list',
    payload: {
      pagination: { page, perPage },
      sort,
      filter: { id: props.id },
    }
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />
  }
  if (error) {
    window.location.reload(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ListContextProvider value={{
        data: keyBy(data, 'id'),
        ids: data.map(({ id }) => id),
        total,
        page,
        perPage,
        setPage,
        setPerPage,
        setSort: (field, order) => {
          setSort({ field, order });
        },
        currentSort: sort,
        basePath: "/list",
        resource: 'lists',
        selectedIds: []
      }}>
        <Datagrid style={{ tableLayout: 'fixed', wordWrap: "break-word" }}>
          <TextField source="id" />
          <TextField source="name" />
        </Datagrid>
        <Pagination rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 50, 100]} />
      </ListContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomList;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve. If you want to filter local data with react-admin, you can look at [the useReferenceArrayFieldController source in react-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/799ea0c1a68e4afbd35596d69eb16ed7579cf6f9/packages/ra-core/src/controller/field/useReferenceArrayFieldController.ts). It's a good example of how to implement pagination, sorting, and filtering locally.

This logic will soon be available via a standalone `useList` hook in react-admin 3.17 (see https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/6321/files#diff-7948760fe1f4dea6953beaf08888f1a3ce5ef2a359a46778b7c7a38af300ccf3):

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import get from 'lodash/get';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import { indexById, removeEmpty, useSafeSetState } from '../util';
import {
    FilterPayload,
    Identifier,
    Record,
    RecordMap,
    SortPayload,
} from '../types';
import usePaginationState from './usePaginationState';
import useSortState from './useSortState';
import useSelectionState from './useSelectionState';
import { ListControllerProps } from '.';

/**
 * Handle filtering, sorting and pagination on local data.
 *
 * Returns the data and callbacks expected by <ListContext>.
 *
 * @example
 * const data = [
 *     { id: 1, name: 'Arnold' },
 *     { id: 2, name: 'Sylvester' },
 *     { id: 3, name: 'Jean-Claude' },
 * ]
 * const ids = [1, 2, 3];
 *
 * const MyComponent = () => {
 *     const listContext = useList({
 *         initialData: data,
 *         initialIds: ids,
 *         basePath: '/resource';
 *         resource: 'resource';
 *     });
 *     return (
 *         <ListContextProvider value={listContext}>
 *             <Datagrid>
 *                 <TextField source="id" />
 *                 <TextField source="name" />
 *             </Datagrid>
 *         </ListContextProvider>
 *     );
 * };
 *
 * @param {UseListOptions} props
 * @param {Record[]} props.data An array of records
 * @param {Identifier[]} props.ids An array of the record identifiers
 * @param {Boolean} props.loaded: A boolean indicating whether the data has been loaded at least once
 * @param {Boolean} props.loading: A boolean indicating whether the data is being loaded
 * @param {Error | String} props.error: Optional. The error if any occured while loading the data
 * @param {Object} props.filter: Optional. An object containing the filters applied on the data
 * @param {Number} props.page: Optional. The initial page index
 * @param {Number} props.perPage: Optional. The initial page size
 * @param {SortPayload} props.sort: Optional. The initial sort (field and order)
 */
export const useList = (props: UseListOptions): UseListValue => {
    const {
        data,
        error,
        filter = defaultFilter,
        ids,
        loaded,
        loading,
        page: initialPage = 1,
        perPage: initialPerPage = 1000,
        sort: initialSort = defaultSort,
    } = props;
    const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useSafeSetState<boolean>(loading);
    const [loadedState, setLoadedState] = useSafeSetState<boolean>(loaded);

    const [finalItems, setFinalItems] = useSafeSetState<{
        data: RecordMap;
        ids: Identifier[];
    }>(() => ({
        data: indexById(data),
        ids,
    }));

    // pagination logic
    const { page, setPage, perPage, setPerPage } = usePaginationState({
        page: initialPage,
        perPage: initialPerPage,
    });

    // sort logic
    const { sort, setSort: setSortObject } = useSortState(initialSort);
    const setSort = useCallback(
        (field: string, order = 'ASC') => {
            setSortObject({ field, order });
            setPage(1);
        },
        [setPage, setSortObject]
    );

    // selection logic
    const {
        selectedIds,
        onSelect,
        onToggleItem,
        onUnselectItems,
    } = useSelectionState();

    // filter logic
    const filterRef = useRef(filter);
    const [displayedFilters, setDisplayedFilters] = useSafeSetState<{
        [key: string]: boolean;
    }>({});
    const [filterValues, setFilterValues] = useSafeSetState<{
        [key: string]: any;
    }>(filter);
    const hideFilter = useCallback(
        (filterName: string) => {
            setDisplayedFilters(previousState => {
                const { [filterName]: _, ...newState } = previousState;
                return newState;
            });
            setFilterValues(previousState => {
                const { [filterName]: _, ...newState } = previousState;
                return newState;
            });
        },
        [setDisplayedFilters, setFilterValues]
    );
    const showFilter = useCallback(
        (filterName: string, defaultValue: any) => {
            setDisplayedFilters(previousState => ({
                ...previousState,
                [filterName]: true,
            }));
            setFilterValues(previousState =>
                removeEmpty({
                    ...previousState,
                    [filterName]: defaultValue,
                })
            );
        },
        [setDisplayedFilters, setFilterValues]
    );
    const setFilters = useCallback(
        (filters, displayedFilters) => {
            setFilterValues(removeEmpty(filters));
            if (displayedFilters) {
                setDisplayedFilters(displayedFilters);
            }
            setPage(1);
        },
        [setDisplayedFilters, setFilterValues, setPage]
    );
    // handle filter prop change
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isEqual(filter, filterRef.current)) {
            filterRef.current = filter;
            setFilterValues(filter);
        }
    });

    // We do all the data processing (filtering, sorting, paginating) client-side
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!loaded) return;

        // 1. filter
        let tempData = data.filter(record =>
            Object.entries(filterValues).every(([filterName, filterValue]) => {
                const recordValue = get(record, filterName);
                const result = Array.isArray(recordValue)
                    ? Array.isArray(filterValue)
                        ? recordValue.some(item => filterValue.includes(item))
                        : recordValue.includes(filterValue)
                    : Array.isArray(filterValue)
                    ? filterValue.includes(recordValue)
                    : filterValue == recordValue; // eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                return result;
            })
        );
        // 2. sort
        if (sort.field) {
            tempData = tempData.sort((a, b) => {
                if (get(a, sort.field) > get(b, sort.field)) {
                    return sort.order === 'ASC' ? 1 : -1;
                }
                if (get(a, sort.field) < get(b, sort.field)) {
                    return sort.order === 'ASC' ? -1 : 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
        }
        // 3. paginate
        tempData = tempData.slice((page - 1) * perPage, page * perPage);
        const finalData = indexById(tempData);
        const finalIds = tempData
            .filter(data => typeof data !== 'undefined')
            .map(data => data.id);

        setFinalItems({
            data: finalData,
            ids: finalIds,
        });
    }, [
        data,
        filterValues,
        loaded,
        page,
        perPage,
        setFinalItems,
        sort.field,
        sort.order,
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loaded !== loadedState) {
            setLoadedState(loaded);
        }
    }, [loaded, loadedState, setLoadedState]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (loading !== loadingState) {
            setLoadingState(loading);
        }
    }, [loading, loadingState, setLoadingState]);

    return {
        currentSort: sort,
        data: finalItems.data,
        error,
        displayedFilters,
        filterValues,
        hideFilter,
        ids: finalItems.ids,
        loaded: loadedState,
        loading: loadingState,
        onSelect,
        onToggleItem,
        onUnselectItems,
        page,
        perPage,
        selectedIds,
        setFilters,
        setPage,
        setPerPage,
        setSort,
        showFilter,
        total: finalItems.ids.length,
    };
};

export interface UseListOptions<RecordType extends Record = Record> {
    data: RecordType[];
    ids: Identifier[];
    error?: any;
    filter?: FilterPayload;
    loading: boolean;
    loaded: boolean;
    page?: number;
    perPage?: number;
    sort?: SortPayload;
}

export type UseListValue = Omit<
    ListControllerProps,
    'resource' | 'basePath' | 'refetch'
>;

const defaultFilter = {};
const defaultSort = { field: null, order: null };
```

Pass the return value of that useList hoot to ListContextProvider, and you should be up and running.

Comment: Essentially I want to have the same type of filter available in the docs above, but on this custom list I'm using. Right now my filter is not local, so I'm trying to make it work similar to how it works in normal <List /> component.

Comment: Essentially, i used this
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#rendering-datagrid-with-a-custom-query
to build a custom list, but not sure how to add filtering of that list to this component.